Find semi-equivalent Euler rotation vectors with one axis zeroed out
I’ve been stumped by a 3d math problem that exploits my weakness in quaternions! I am visualizing data from a physical sensor in unity / c#.
I have a ‘rod’ object with a rotation represented by the euler vector (x,y,z). The roll of the rod is represented by the y axis. In the image I added a cube to the rod so the roll is obvious.
I would like to manipulate the rotation of the rod so that the Y euler is 0, and X and Z are modified to ensure the rod still points in the same direction (just with a different roll, since I don’t care about roll). For example, I’ve attached 3 images. One with the un-rotated rod (image A), one with the rod’s rotation set to (0,90,90) (image B), and one with the rod’s rotation set to (90, 0, 0) (image C). Notice that the rod is pointing in the exact same direction in image B and C, just with a different roll.
Is there a way to create an algorithm that sets a Euler’s y to 0, then adjusts the X and Z to accommodate the change and ensure the direction points in the same direction? Or is the example that I posted just a lucky edge case that can’t be reproduced for all Eulers?
imgur link for visual aids in case these links don't work: https://imgur.com/a/unity-question-J9KahZK
[image A](https://i.sstatic.net/65hD11nB.png)
[image B](https://i.sstatic.net/2fvgUyFM.png)
[image C](https://i.sstatic.net/yVQ3ix0w.png)

I've attached what I currently have in C# to show what currently works. This visualizes the rod's rotation properly along the x and z axis, but has a roll that I'd like to negate (which I can't do simply by setting y to 0 as that modifies the rotation on the x and z axes).
public Transform armTransform;
private Quaternion defaultArmRotation;
private Quaternion armOffset;
private Vector3 armOffsetEuler;
private bool isArmOffset = false;

...
...

float dataX = parsedXValue;
float dataY = parsedYValue;
float dataZ = parsedZValue;

// Create a vector from the magnetometer data
Vector3 magnetField = new Vector3(dataX, dataY, dataZ);

// Normalize the vector
magnetField.Normalize();


// Calculate the quaternion rotation based on the adjusted Euler angles
Quaternion rotation = Quaternion.LookRotation(magnetField, Vector3.up);

// Set the initial offset if not already set
if (!isArmOffset)
{
    armOffsetEuler = defaultArmRotation.eulerAngles - eulerAngles;
    armOffset = Quaternion.Inverse(rotation) * defaultArmRotation;
    isArmOffset = true;
}

Vector3 newEulerAngles = eulerAngles + armOffsetEuler;

// Apply the offset to the current rotation
Quaternion adjustedRotation = rotation * armOffset;

// Apply the rotation to the game object
armTransform.rotation = adjustedRotation;

I have also been able to make a method that does what I want for the X axis with y always being 0, but the Z value here only returns 180 or -180 or 0.
public Vector3 GetXZRotationWithoutY(Vector3 eulerRotation)
{
    // Convert Euler angles to a Quaternion
    Quaternion rotation = Quaternion.Euler(eulerRotation);

    // Get the right and forward vectors
    Vector3 right = rotation * Vector3.right;
    Vector3 forward = rotation * Vector3.forward;

    // Calculate the new Euler angles
    float xAngle = Mathf.Atan2(forward.y, forward.z) * Mathf.Rad2Deg;
    float zAngle = Mathf.Atan2(right.y, right.x) * Mathf.Rad2Deg;

    return new Vector3(xAngle, 0, zAngle);
}


Some minor tweaks to what I had seems to have done the trick.


void Update()
{
    // Parse out the Arduino data into x, y, z orientation
    float dataX = parsedX;
    float dataY = parsedY;
    float dataZ = parsedZ;

    // Create a vector from the magnetometer data
    Vector3 magnetField = new Vector3(dataX, dataY, dataZ);

    // Normalize the vector
    magnetField.Normalize();

    // Convert the magnetFieldZeroY to Euler angles
    Vector3 eulerAngles = Quaternion.LookRotation(magnetField, Vector3.up).eulerAngles;
    eulerAngles = GetXZRotationWithoutY(eulerAngles);


    // Calculate the quaternion rotation based on the adjusted Euler angles
    Quaternion rotation = Quaternion.Euler(eulerAngles);

    // Set the initial offset if not already set
    if (!isArmOffset)
    {
        armOffset = Quaternion.Inverse(rotation) * defaultArmRotation;
        isArmOffset = true;
    }

    Vector3 newEulerAngles = eulerAngles + armOffsetEuler;

    // Apply the offset to the current rotation
    Quaternion adjustedRotation = rotation * armOffset;

    // Apply the rotation to the game object
    armTransform.rotation = adjustedRotation;
}

public Vector3 GetXZRotationWithoutY(Vector3 eulerRotation)
{
    // Convert Euler angles to a Quaternion
    Quaternion rotation = Quaternion.Euler(eulerRotation);

    // Get the current forward direction
    Vector3 forward = rotation * Vector3.forward;

    // Calculate the new X and Z angles while setting Y to 0
    float xAngle = Mathf.Atan2(forward.y, forward.z) * Mathf.Rad2Deg;
    float zAngle = Mathf.Atan2(forward.x, forward.z) * Mathf.Rad2Deg;

    return new Vector3(-xAngle, 0, zAngle);
}



